# Install coverage-3.0.1 to gentoo

Tags: installation, gentoo

I have installed coverage-2.85 version, but I need [coverage-3.0.1](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/coverage)

I have last version of portage.

```
[I] dev-python/coverage
     Available versions:  2.77 2.85 {test}
     Installed versions:  2.85(12:52:43 PM 08/10/2009)(-test)
     Homepage:            http://nedbatchelder.com/code/modules/coverage.html
     Description:         Measures code coverage during Python execution
```

coverage-3.0.1 - is unavailable even masked.

How can I install this?

I'm beginner in gentoo, please help me with creating ebuild overlay, for this package.

Answer (score 1):

If it's not in Portage then it means that nobody has created and QA'ed an ebuild for it yet.

I would suggest:

1. Create your own ebuild and install it from a [local overlay](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Overlay) for now.
2. File a [bug](http://bugs.gentoo.org/) for it's inclusion in Portage. If you can include an ebuild and details about it's stability then it should speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

You can install packages from PyPI using Python's `setuptools`. First, emerge `setuptools`:

```
$ emerge -av dev-python/setuptools
```

Then, as root, you can run `easy_install` to install `coverage`:

```
$ easy_install coverage
```

Note that with previous versions of `coverage` I was having issues because for some reason `/usr/bin/coverage` was being loaded when Python files were importing it. In order to get around this, I renamed `/usr/bin/coverage` to `/usr/bin/coverage-bin` or something similar.

Comment: Thank you!
It work. But this isn't Gentoo way! :)

Comment: That's true, but I find many Python packages which are useful but don't have an ebuild maintainer. That's why I end up using a mixture of both portage and setuptools for Python packages. I haven't shot myself in the foot yet! :P